# Unable to run ForEach for list in terraform

Tags: terraform, azureservicebus, terraform-provider-azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to create Servicebus topics and subscriptions, and following referring this [link](https://github.com/innovationnorway/terraform-azurerm-service-bus) and updating few things, I am trying to run for each for the topic creation, it is throwing the error

> │ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each"
> argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you
> gs, and you      │ have provided a value of type tuple.

Here is what I am trying

```
variable "topics" {
  type        = any
  default     = [
    {
      name = "testtopic"
      subscriptions = [
        {
          name = "testsubscription"
          rules = [{
            name = "SucceededRule",
            sql_filter = "Status = 'Succeeded'"
          }]
        },
        {
          name = "readysubscription"
          rules = [{
            name = "ReadyRule",
            sql_filter = "Status = 'Ready'"
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  description = "List of topics."
}

locals {
  topics = [
    for topic in var.topics : merge({
      name                       = ""
      status                     = "Active"
      auto_delete_on_idle        = null
      default_message_ttl        = null
      enable_batched_operations  = null
      enable_express             = null
      enable_partitioning        = null
      max_size                   = null
      enable_duplicate_detection = null
      enable_ordering            = null
      authorization_rules        = []
      subscriptions              = []

      duplicate_detection_history_time_window = null
    }, topic)
  ]}
```

maintf

```
resource "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "topic" {
  for_each = toset(local.topics)

  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  namespace_name      = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.servicebus.name

  status                       = each.value.status
  auto_delete_on_idle          = each.value.auto_delete_on_idle
  default_message_ttl          = each.value.default_message_ttl
  enable_batched_operations    = each.value.enable_batched_operations
  enable_express               = each.value.enable_express
  enable_partitioning          = each.value.enable_partitioning
  max_size_in_megabytes        = each.value.max_size
  requires_duplicate_detection = each.value.enable_duplicate_detection
  support_ordering             = each.value.enable_ordering

  duplicate_detection_history_time_window = each.value.duplicate_detection_history_time_window
}
```

Comment: your topic variable is indeed a tuple because of the `, topic)`. Not sure why you are adding the topic in a tuple

Comment: I have tried without that as well, it didnt help. Its the same error I am getting

Comment: have you tried `for_each = local.topics` instead?

Comment: yes, its the same response.

Comment: I am assuming this is < 0.15, or some other restriction from using nested variable defaults or optional attributes in the experimental features. The design pattern makes sense in that situation, and your usage inside the `locals` is mostly fine (i.e. some values seem unused). Syntactically it also seems fine, and I have a difficult time reconciling your error message with the provided code. Is this reproducible?

Comment: I am using TF version 0.15.4 and AzureRm 2.75.0, Its reproducible, I have pushed it to here https://github.com/PrakashRajanSakthivel/terraform-sb, if that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can create all of your resources using a `count`:

```
resource "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "topic" {
    count = len(local.topics)

    name                = each.value.name
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    namespace_name      = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.servicebus.name

    status              = local.topics[count.index].status
    ...
}
```

That avoids the mess of trying to turn a bunch of objects into a set.

Edit:

If you need a for_each to pull out objects by name, use a map. Pick a key that you know will be unique - in this case I used 'name':

```
locals {
    topics = {}
        for topic in var.topics : topic.name = merge({
        name                       = ""
        status                     = "Active"
        ...
        duplicate_detection_history_time_window = null
    }, topic)
]}
```

The local is now an object. it will need to be a map:

```
 resource "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "topic" {
    for_each = tomap(local.topics)

    name                = each.value.name
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    namespace_name      = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.servicebus.name

    status              = each.value.status
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have the version of code with count which works fine. I was going through some articles about for_each, I thought of migrating it to foreach thats where I am facing this issue. https://medium.com/@business_99069/terraform-count-vs-for-each-b7ada2c0b186